# Django application is not recognized when running

Tags: python, django, module, virtualenv

I am new to Django and I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aJ49vtM3nQ&list=PLMyNvIPi_kYF8oUnMiyTk_M92gJz9WvZt&index=30

I added a new application called firstapp, but it seems like it is not recognized and i don't know why. I added it to the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'firstapp',
]
```

but when trying to import it only works if i add the main project in front of it:
[image] in which case i get an error when trying to run the server.
[image]
[image] in which case i get a "not found" error.

I mention that I activated a virtual environment using Anaconda Prompt based on the tutorial, but I am not sure how to check if that is the problem.
[image]

edit: by modifying the path to : `path(r'',views.index, name="index"),` it worked, but the import from firstapp is still displayed as an error so I don't really understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import it directly because your "firstapp" is inside your "startProject" directory.
It is better approach to declare the URLs of your "firstapp" inside its own url.py file and then include that url.py file to your "startProject" url.py. Like this

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
   path('', include('firstapp.urls')),
]
```